# Add object on upload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I'm using the S3 Direct Uploader Rails gem.

In my coffeescript, I have:

```
$("#s3-uploader").S3Uploader()

urls = {}

$('#s3-uploader').bind 's3_upload_complete', (e, content) ->
  $parent = $("#s3-uploader").parent()
  urls.url = content.url

console.log(urls)
```

Basically, when a upload is completed, I want to add the url to a JSON object (called **urls**). But when I console.log urls, it just returns `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code looks, the `console.log` is executed upon execution of your script, while the `s3_upload_complete` method is run asynchronously when the event fires. Please try putting your `console.log` into your event handler and test it again.

```
$("#s3-uploader").S3Uploader()

urls = {}

$('#s3-uploader').bind 's3_upload_complete', (e, content) ->
  $parent = $("#s3-uploader").parent()
  urls.url = content.url

  console.log(urls)
```